# System.out.println not working with numbers

Tags: java, numbers, system

I have the following code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


    public class weatherCalc {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            while (true) {
                int division = 8125/1000;
                Scanner in = new Scanner;
                System.out.println("How far, in inches, is it moving on a 50-mile = 0.75 in? (Please use decimels)");
                int weatherInput = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("How long is the time period in hours? (Please use decimels)");
                int weatherTime = in.nextInt();
                int weatherOutput = weatherInput/division*50/weatherTime;
                System.out.println("The storm is travling at "+ weatherOutput +"MPH.");
            }
        }
    }
```

You see, the System in "System.out.println("How far, in inches, is it moving on a 50-mile = 0.75 in? (Please use decimels)");" is underlined with red along with the end of "Scanner in = new Scanner;" I can not figure out why, and am just trying to develop this for myself. I might later work on it a little. If anyone can tell me why, it would help a lot.

Comment: I'm not a big java dev, but it looks like you are trying to concatenate a string with an integer. Is that allowed in Java?

Comment: What error message says? Also be careful with dividing integers since result will also be integer. `8125/1000` is not `8.125` but `8`.

Comment: @brbcoding Yes, it is allowed. Java automatically calls `toString()` on any object concatenated to a `String` (as long as the first object in the concatenation chain is a `String`).

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but it's spelled "decimal," not "decimel." I'm mainly letting you know because I couldn't figure out what looked wrong about it, until I realized my brain was conflating it as equal parts "decimal" and "decibel."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner;
```

should be:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: I think Scanner need argument. `System.in`

Comment: @Eng.Fouad That won't compile.

Comment: Ah, missed that. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop should be like this: (watch the comments specified against each changed code)

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);//Move the Scanner declaration outside loop . Don't create it every-time within the loop.
while (true) {
  int division = 8125/1000;
  System.out.println("How far, in inches, is it moving on a 50-mile = 0.75 in? (Please use decimels)");
  int weatherInput = in.nextInt();
  System.out.println("How long is the time period in hours? (Please use decimels)");
  double weatherTime = in.nextDouble();//Take double value from input as u have specified that you want input in decimals.
  double weatherOutput = weatherInput/division*50/weatherTime;//Changed weatherOutput type to double so that you get the result in double.
  System.out.println("The storm is travling at "+ weatherOutput +"MPH.");
 }
```

Comment: Is the only difference that you moved `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);` outside the loop? You're right, that is the better place for it, but you could clarify that that's what should be changed. Unless there's something else?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Other difference is too..yeah..I am putting the comment..against those lines..